# Каждому пользователю - свой background

Tags: jquery, php

Доброе время суток. Имеется простой сайт php + jQuery, с регистрацией и входом на сайт. Можно ли организовать например как на [twitter.com](http://twitter.com) чтобы пользователь мог выбирать фон для сайта из предложенных вариантов или загрузить свой. Рассмотрю все варианты. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @jkwe45, пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: background-image:url(img/fon.png);

Comment: Сам еще ничего не сделал, по причине того, что не знаю как реализовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. В таблице `users` создать поле `bg`
2. Пользователь в аккаунте вписывает номер цвета фона #ff0000 (красный) или просто red, нажимает сохранить данное значение попадает в строку `bg`
3. Затем будет выборка цвета. Например вот так:

   ```
   <?php
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT bg FROM `users` WHERE id='".$id."'");
   $res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   ?>

   <html>
       <body id="bg">
        <style>
            body#bg {
            background: <?php echo $res['bg']; ?>
            }
        <style>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Но это так, самое простое решение. Вообщем то таким методом можно и загрузку изображений организовать. Главное что бы при загрузке, в БД добавлялось имя  изображения

Answer (score 3):

В базе добавляешь для пользователя либо поле "фон", либо таблицу со свойствами если таковых будет много. После авторизации подгружаешь нужную картинку.

Comment: Спасибо @nMike, а как загрузить таблицу стилей только для этого пользователя?

Comment: Ну надо вначале узнать, что это за пользователь (через куки там, или сессию, тут вопрос в том, как Вы это реализуете). Потом запрос в базу с SELECT'ом имени файла фона. А потом генерируете уже html страницу (встраиваете либо в style, либо в class) свойство background:url() со значением которое Вы извлекли.